# Using the WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration() function using remote server and port?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, remote-access, webconfigurationmanager

Can someone tell me if there is a  way for me to use the WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration() using a remote server, port and virtual directory?

Examples cited in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228063.aspx and http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/management/mgmtapi.aspx only use the virtual path and server.

In my setup I have a webservice that resides on the root (defaultsite) of a remote server on a specific port (e.g 1570). I would like to connect and retrieve a configuration setting from the web.config file of this webservice.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this might be what you need?

http://forums.asp.net/p/991344/1291011.aspx#1291011